# Is Ubuntu MAAS only for Servers?

Tags: maas

I'm trying to get my head around using Ubuntu MAAS as a means to deploy clients. All the documentation I see exclusively mentions servers. Can I use the MAAS platform to deploy a regular Ubuntu Desktop OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu MAAS (Metal as a Service) is what you can use to build your own version of Amazon Web Services, DigitalOcean, etc. MAAS is very much built for the datacenter<sup>1</sup>. If you are going to be performing a mass deployment of Ubuntu Desktop installations, you may want to look at [the FAI Project](https://fai-project.org), which allows for a fully-automatic installation of Ubuntu (and some other distributions). [The documentation](https://fai-project.org/fai-guide/) is incredibly thorough and the tool sees regular updates.

---

<sup>1</sup> there are "consumer" versions of MAAS but, even then, it's designed for a very different purpose to desktop deployments.